# This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension

Tags: typescript, unit-testing

I want to use `jtest` to do a unit test in the typescript (Node version v16.13.2) project. First I install the jtest `"jest": "^27.5.1"` and add `jest.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    roots: [
        "<rootDir>/test"
    ],
    testRegex: 'test/(.+)\\.test\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$',
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
};
```

Add the test entry:

```
import DeviceHandler from "@utils/data/DeviceHandler";

test('hello world test', () => {
    let deviceId = DeviceHandler.getDeviceId();
    expect(deviceId).toBe("xxxx");
});
```

But when I run the test command `yarn test`:

```
ReferenceError: module is not defined in ES module scope
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/Users/dolphin/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
    at file:///Users/dolphin/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/jest.config.js:1:1
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:185:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:281:24)
    at async importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:437:15)
    at async requireOrImportModule (/Users/dolphin/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/jest-util/build/requireOrImportModule.js:65:32)
    at async readConfigFileAndSetRootDir (/Users/dolphin/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/jest-config/build/readConfigFileAndSetRootDir.js:132:22)
    at async readConfig (/Users/dolphin/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/jest-config/build/index.js:233:18)
    at async readConfigs (/Users/dolphin/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/jest-config/build/index.js:420:26)
    at async runCLI (/Users/dolphin/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:132:59)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
(base)
```

This is the `DeviceHandler.ts` content:

```
const DeviceHandler = {
    getDeviceId: async() : Promise<string> => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve("xxxx");
        });
    },
    getDeviceIdEnhance: async (): Promise<string> => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // Initialize an agent at application startup.
            const fpPromise = require('@fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs').load();
            // Get the visitor identifier when you need it.
            fpPromise
                .then((fp: { get: () => any; }) => fp.get())
                .then(async (result: { visitorId: any; }) => {
                    // This is the visitor identifier:
                    const deviceId = result.visitorId;
                    resolve(deviceId);
                });
        });
    }
};

export default DeviceHandler;
```

Why did this error happen? what should I do to make the unit test work?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You probably have `"type": "module"` in your `package.json` file. If you remove that it will fix this.

Alternatively, if you want to keep your `"type": "module"` you could convert your `jest.config.js` to be `jest.config.json` (and/or if you have a `babel.config.js` you will need to convert that one to be `babel.config.json` as well). Note that you will actually have to convert it to be in JSON format (so, remove `module.exports =`  from it, etc).

[This example project](https://github.com/cmcculloh/jest-import) goes way more in depth on all this

Comment: this is very helpful! Thanks. You can also use `module.exports =` in jest and babel config files by rename them to `jest.config.cjs` and `babel.config.cjs`.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this error today and wanted to keep my library as `"type": "module"` in my `package.json` so I changed my `jest.config.js` to `jest.config.json` as [cmcculloh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71345603/197674) suggests. I had to make changes to the file to accommodate the change.

`jest.config.js`:

```js
/* eslint-disable */
module.exports = {
  displayName: '@company/admin-lib',
  preset: '../../../jest.preset.js',
  transform: {
    '^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)': '@nx/react/plugins/jest',
    '^.+\\.[tj]sx?$': ['babel-jest', { presets: ['@nx/react/babel'] }],
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx'],
  coverageDirectory: '../../../coverage/packages/@company/admin-lib',
};
```

The equivalent `jest.config.json` would be:

```json
{
  "displayName": "@company/admin-lib",
  "preset": "../../../jest.preset.js",
  "transform": {
    "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "@nx/react/plugins/jest",
    "^.+\\.[tj]sx?$": ["babel-jest", { "presets": ["@nx/react/babel"] }]
  },
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx"],
  "coverageDirectory": "../../../coverage/packages/@company/admin-lib"
}
```