# Nuxt.js problematic nuxt.config.js/ts with Firebase Cloud Functions while deploying ES5/6 modules / compatibility issue

Tags: firebase, ecmascript-6, google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to deploy `Nuxt.js (2)` SSR app to `Firebase Hosting/Functions`. I'm able to do that, as long as I won't include `nuxt.config.ts` in `functions/src/index.ts`. However, I do have some setup there, such as meta tags, I'd like to push.

That's my `nuxt.config.js` file (basically default `Firebase` starter for `.ts` + `nuxt` imports):

```
const { Nuxt } = require('nuxt-start')
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const nuxtConfig = require('./../nuxt.config.ts')

const config = {
  ...nuxtConfig,
  dev: false,
  debug: false,
}

const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

exports.ssrapp = functions.https.onRequest(async (req: any, res: any) => {
  await nuxt.ready()
  nuxt.render(req, res)
})
```

Using both `module.exports = { ... }` and `export default { ... }` inside `nuxt.config.ts` returns:

```
Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

then I add `"type": "module"` to `functions/package.json` (changing `package.json` in `root` won't help) and that's what I can see:

```
Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'path/to/my/project/functions/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
```

I try to change from `export default` to `module.exports = { ... }` inside `nuxt.config.ts` and it gives me the same error `Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source:...`

I've tried to change to `import * as nuxtConfig from './../nuxt.config'` while keeping `module.exports = { ... }` inside `nuxt.config.ts`, but success either, code is generated the same, and it creates `src` folder inside `functions/lib` complicating further the structure of `Firebase` project.

Changing back to `export default { ... }` inside `nuxt.config.ts` and keeping `import * as nuxtConfig from './../nuxt.config'` returns again:

```
Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'path/to/my/project/Doyban-Website/functions/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
```

Lastly, I've tried to use all `import`'s inside `functions/index.ts`

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
// @ts-ignore
import Nuxt from 'nuxt-start'
import * as nuxtConfig from './../nuxt.config'

const config = {
  ...nuxtConfig,
  dev: false,
  debug: false,
}

const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

exports.ssrapp = functions.https.onRequest(async (req: any, res: any) => {
  await nuxt.ready()
  nuxt.render(req, res)
})
```

the result:

```
Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'path/to/my/project/Doyban-Website/functions/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
```

I have no idea :-(

Comment: I've followed those 2 tutorials https://medium.com/@sirofjelly/deploying-a-nuxt-ssr-server-side-rendering-app-to-google-firebase-5d90117167db & https://ben-mayer.com/blog/building-a-web-app-using-nuxtjs-and-firebase

Comment: can you check this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71321728/this-file-is-being-treated-as-an-es-module-because-it-has-a-js-file-extension)

Comment: @SathiAiswarya, do you mean to make a `nuxt.config.json` out of `nuxt.config.js`?

Comment: @kissu, do you have any idea? I've seen your contribution to related topic: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73756329/11127383.  The repo, rather quick setup just firebase project init & deploy is needed: https://github.com/Doyban/Doyban-Website. The project deployed on Firebase https://doyban-website-nuxtjs.web.app (with commented out `nuxtConfig` inside `functions/index.ts`. I just pushed the changes!